# How do I find a list of people so I can request them as a friend?

Tags: facebook

I recently got a new phone and want to request all my friends to accept a friend request. I need a list of Facebook users so I can ask.

Answer (score 2):

Save all your friends name and number in your new mobile phone as contacts. Install Facebook app and login to your account. After sometime Facebook will show you your contacts to invite them on Facebook (if they are not on Facebook) or to send them request.

<sup>Tested this on Android. Not sure about other OS.</sup>